# Unable to push notifications to iPhone in .NET - .PEM certificate problem?

Tags: c#, iphone, push-notification

I'm attempting to push notifications to my iPhone, which I've successfully done using PHP.  However, I'm unable to open a socket connection to Apple's push servers using C#.  I don't think there's a problem with the certificate itself, since I'm able to successfully push notifications using this code in PHP:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

fwrite($fp, $msg);
```

When I try to authenticate in C# using the code below, Apple closes the connection right away.  I get this exception: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

I basically took all my code from this question: [C# iPhone push server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056083/c-iphone-push-server)

I thought it might be a problem with the certificate since I don't think C# allows you to just load .PEM files programmatically.  I used OpenSSL to convert it to a .PFX file, but I still have the same problem.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this (possible certificate) problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be a problem with .NET 2.0.  Not sure exactly what it is, but I compiled in Visual Studio 2008 and everything worked great.